# Multiple Resource file groups in .NET 6 Web API

Tags: c#, localization, .net-6.0, webapi

I have an .NET 6 Web API, where I need to have multiple Resource files, my question is - Is it possible to have a way to read from the specific resource file at a given time.

**Resource files**

Resource1.resx

Resource1.en.resx

Resource1.es-ES.resx

...

Resource2.resx

Resource2.en.resx

Resource2.pt-BR.resx

...

Now in my code I can read like

```
_localizer.Get("Resource1", "key") 
_localizer.Get("Resource2", "key")
```